# ResolvePath for VB6 - resolve environment variables

Tags: vb6, environment-variables

I am looking for a function in VB6 (or some WinAPI) that might be able to satisfy this requirement: Take an input path string that includes environment variables, and output that path with environment variables resolved.

For example:

- Input: `"%windir%\System32\"`
- Output: `"C:\Windows\System32\"`

I could of course write my own parser, but I am wondering if this functionality already exists?

This would be similar to the [Spring Framework's "`ResolvePath`" method](http://www.springframework.net/doc-1.1-M1/sdk/2.0/html/Spring.Core~Spring.Core.IO.ResourceConverter~ResolvePath.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Worst case you can use the native implementation: [`ExpandEnvironmentStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724265.aspx)

Comment: Or in .NET Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Kernel32.dll exports a function called [`ExpandEnvironmentStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724265%28VS.85%29.aspx):

My VB6 is rusty but you can call this by doing:

```
Declare Function ExpandEnvironmentStrings _
   Lib "kernel32" Alias "ExpandEnvironmentStringsA" _
   (ByVal lpSrc As String, ByVal lpDst As String, _
   ByVal nSize As Long) As Long
```

Then in a function or sub:

```
Dim result as Long
Dim strInput As String, strOutput As String
'' Two calls required, one to get expansion buffer length first then do expansion
result = ExpandEnvironmentStrings(strInput, strOutput, result)
strOutput = Space$(result)
result = ExpandEnvironmentStrings(strInput, strOutput, result)
```

Comment: Not quite right, you'll need to allocate some space for strOutput before you call `ExpandEnvironmentStrings`. You could do `result = 0: result = ExpandEnvironmentStrings(strInput, strOutput, result): strOutput = Space$(result): result = ExpandEnvironmentStrings(strInput, strOutput, result)`

Comment: @MarkJ - thanks for catching that. I don't have VB6 installed any more though can see the old Visual Studio 6 box of CD's from 1999 on a shelf from here :)

Comment: +1 That now works in VB6 on my machine. +1 for keeping the disks too :)

Answer (score -1):

Using the seldom used Environ() Function: http://vbcity.com/forums/t/45987.aspx

Comment: Ya, that would work if I wrote my own parser.  I'm wondering if the parser already exists somewhere.  Dir() has a 101 different uses, and perhaps the winapi has one.